Does the average of unit-norm vectors maximize the sum of cosine distances to each of the original vectors?
It's easy to show that minimizing squared L2 distance is equivalent to maximizing cosine similarity, assuming X1 and X2 are unit vectors:

since the term in brackets is the cosine distance (1 - cos similarity), and so the two metrics are proportional.
It's also relatively well known that the average of vectors minimizes the sum of squared L2 distances to each vector. This is the basis for the K-means algorithm, among other things. Another part of the K-means algorithm is that minimizing the sum of squared L2 distances to that centroid is equivalent to minimizing the squared pairwise deviations.
So when the vectors themselves are unit norm, the squared pairwise deviations all follow that formula above of L2 $\alpha$ CosineSim. But the average itself will not have unit norm. So it seems to me that even though the average minimizes sum of squared L2 to each individual vector, it doesn't actually guarantee that it is the point that maximizes the sum of cosine similarities to those same vectors. I realize that the norm itself doesn't matter for cosine similarity, but the problem ends up feeling kind of circular to me, so any help is appreciated.
